# Try to understand how to build an array from int params

Tags: go

All:

When I try to follow golang's Tour of Go:

[Exercise: Slices](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/18)

My code is like this:

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    const x = dx
    const y = dy
    pic := [y][x]uint8{};

    for r:=range pic {
        row := pic[r]
        for c := range row {
            row[c] = uint8(c*r) 
        }
    }

    return pic[:]
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

And I got error like:

```
prog.go:6:8: const initializer dx is not a constant
prog.go:7:8: const initializer dy is not a constant
```

I am pretty new to Go, **I wonder what this error means, and if I want to build an array first(other than using make() to build slice), how can I pass the length of array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Error**

The error comes from trying to define a constant from a variable. In Go, constants must be defined as literals or expressions built from other constants. Your `x` and `y` are defined differently depending on the input of the `Pic` function. In general, constants are defined at compile time.

For example the following are fine in Go:

```
const w = 100
const x = 200
const y = w + x
const z = x + y + 300
```

But the following is not:

```
var x = 100
const y = x + 10
```

and this second example is essentially what is happening in your code since `dx` and `dy` vary depending on the input to the `Pic` function.

If you're coming from JavaScript, which also has the `const` keyword, this might seem like strange behavior. In JavaScript a constant is basically just a variable that can't be changed after it is declared. In Go, a constant is more constant than in JS.

Check out this post for more on constants in Go: https://blog.golang.org/constants

**Creating the Array**

Array sizes have similar constraints to constant values in Go. In this example, if you try to set the Array's size equal to `dx` or `dy`, you will get the error:

> non-constant array bound dx

Thus you will have to use a Slice in this example. The simplest way would be to define your Slice with length `dy` like:

```
pic := make([][]uint8, dy)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution

Answer (score 1):

There are no constant values. For example,

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    p := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for x := range p {
        p[x] = make([]uint8, dx)
        for y := range p[x] {
            p[x][y] = uint8(x * y)
        }
    }
    return p
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/JQwGhfBth0o

Comment: Thanks for the solution